Prove : For any element not in the closed set A $\exists \delta$ s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$, $|x-a| \geq \delta$ for a$\notin A$
To Prove:
Let A be a non empty and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ . If $a \notin A$ then show that $\exists$ $\delta> 0$ s.t.
$|x-a| \geq \delta$ $ \forall x\in A$
Proof:
A is a closed set $\iff$ $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is an open set.
$\therefore$ $\exists$ $\delta> 0$ s.t. $N_\delta(a) \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus A $.
But since $N_\delta(a) \not\subset A $,
$\therefore$ $\forall x \in A$,  $|x-a| \not< \delta$ $\iff$ $|x-a| \geq \delta$.
Is this correct way? can anyone help make this more better.

This does not work. How did you conclude that $|x-a| \not< \delta$ for $x \in A$?

if it would have been less than $\delta$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$ would be true, which is not possible, is this correct argument?

Try the contrapositive: it’s simpler

You are reading $B \not \subset A$ as $B \subset A^{c}$.

Yes, i want to convey that for that particular $\delta$ all elements in $N_\delta(a)$ are not present in A

$N_{\delta}(a)$ may contain some elements of $A$ and your $x$ may be one of them.

BTW, it is enough if $A$ is closed. Compacteness is not needed.

Got it,  thanks @geetha290krm

@lhf thanks for the hint

This should be much easier for you. Fix $a\notin A$
If there does not exist such a $\delta$ such that $|x-a|\geq\delta\,,\forall x\in A$, then for each $n$, you can find an $x_{n}\in A$ such that $|x_{n}-a|<\frac{1}{n}$.
Where does $x_{n}$ converge to? If $A$ is closed, then must the limit of $x_{n}$'s belong to $A$? Would that contradict something?

$x_{n} \rightarrow a$ where $a \not\in A$ .$x_{n}$ sequence in A converges to point not in the set A ,contradicting the hypothesis that A is a closed  /compact set.

is this the right implication and negation statement using logic operator:
If A is compact and $a\ \not\in A$  $\implies$ $(\forall x \in A)(\exists \delta>0)(|x-a| \geq \delta)$
Negation of consequence:
$(\forall \delta > 0)(\exists x \in A)(|x-a|< \delta)$

Both of your comments are correct. In both cases, just replace compact by closed as that is more general. @hr08
